# Redirect to next post after form submit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to implement a feature -

In which a user can `rate` blogs in one page and after user click `Save Rate` then user will redirect to next review blog page and user will ratenext blog.
But it is not redirecting to next rate blog page.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

Rating_Choice = [('1','1'), ('2','2')]

class Rate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Rating_Choice)
```

views.py

```
def rate_blog_post(request, blog_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)

    next_blog = Blog.objects.filter(rate__ratings=None)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post= form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.blog = data
            post.save()

    # redirect here
            return redirect('rate_blog_post', pk=data.id)

    else:
        form = Form()

    context = {'obj':obj, 'form':form}
    return render(request, rate_blog_post.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
    path('rate_blog_post/<int:blog_id>/', views.rate_blog_post, name='rate_blog_post'),
```

- Form is working fine, it is saving the ratings

**What have i tried so far ? :**

- I have tried using a `next_blog` like :-

```
return redirect('rate_blog_post', rate_blog_post=blog_id)
```

But it showed

> Reverse for 'rate_blog_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found

> **NOTE** :- `next_blog` contains multiple blogs, But i didn't find any other way to use like `get_object_or_404(Blog,pk=blog_id,  rate__ratings =None)`, So it will redirect to next blog post id which have rating = None

- Than i tried `get_object_or_404(Blog,pk=blog_id,  rate__ratings =None)`

Than it shows .

> Reverse for 'rate_blog_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rate_blog_post/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$']

I have tried many times but did't worked for me.

I will really appreciate your Help. Thank You

So, i made a choices of reviews. And User will redirect to next post which have choice `None`,

Comment: `return redirect('rate_blog_post', rate_blog_post=question_id)` should be `return redirect('rate_blog_post', blog_id=question_id)`

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo (question_id), But it is still showing `No Blog matches the given query.` And I am trying to redirect on next page, **Not** on previous post.

Comment: `return redirect('rate_blog_post', pk=data.id)` should be `redirect('rate_blog_post', blog_id=data.id)`

Comment: Still showing that *Not Found* Error

Comment: What is the urlpattern for `rate_blog_post`?

Comment: @Van next_blog is a queryset containing multiple blogs ?

Comment: @Shiv, Updated the `urls.py`

Comment: @Prakhar, Yes it contains multiple blogs, But i didn't find any other way to use like `get_object_or_404(Blog,pk=blog_id,  rate__ratings =None)`, So it will redirect to next blog post id which have `rating = None`

Comment: @Van Can you please make a small github repository and I can take a look. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using `postgresql` , And Let me think (quickly) , about Github

Comment: @Shiv, I have uploaded only required files, [Github Link](https://github.com/testingyy/Review-Blog)

Comment: okay give me few hours and I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Shiv, It is solved by Prakhar now

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies here :

```
next_blog = Blog.objects.filter(rate__ratings=None)

return redirect('rate_blog_post', pk=data.id)
```

First :
Query a single blog you want to visit next, not multiple

```
next_blog = Blog.objects.filter(rate__ratings="").order_by('id')[0]
```

Second :
use `pk=next_blog.id` while redirecting

```
return redirect('rate_blog_post', blog_id=next_blog.id)
```

```
ratings = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Rating_Choice, default="")
```

This should resolve the issue

Comment: When i use `pk=next_blog.id` than it is showing `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Did you changed your next_blog query ?

Comment: No sir, I didn't, But as i mentioned , I didn't find any way to query only one post which have `ratings=None`

Comment: As you see, I am querying `Blog.objects.filter(rate__ratings=None)`. I am using `model lookup` like `rate__ratings`. First i am accessing model name `rate` than the field name. And i have also tried by printing this query , it is showing the blogs which have `ratings=None`

Comment: @Van Try out now

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#null Here is why you shouldn't use `NULL` on `charfield`

Comment: It is still showing `Reverse for 'rate_blog_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rate_blog_post/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$']`, But thing is , When i rate on `id=1` then it is showing as error `id=2` in the error url, So it means it is going but something is still wrong

Comment: pls use `blog_id=next_blog.id`

Comment: Sorry, I accidently close the chrome tab and i forgot the password of previous account so, i borrowed someone's account, Back on the problem, It is not showing any error but it is not redirecting on next page it is still on that post after submit,

Comment: did u made migrations etc after the field changes, also make sure blogs those are not rated have there ratings set as ""

Comment: And when i submit form two times than it is redirecting to next page but not on one time, AND Yes i made after changes

Comment: that is because, we are querying next_blog first then saving form data. We should query after rating is saved,just before redirecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236998/discussion-between-prakhar-and-van).

Comment: Thank You Very Much for your Precious Time, You're genius . It is working now. This is first time someone spent so much time on my question or any question. Thank Again,

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding :)